# Fastest use of a dataset of just over 64 bytes?

Tags: c, cpu-cache

**Structure:** I have 8 64-bit integers (512 bits = 64 bytes, the assumed cache line width) that I would like to compare to another, single 64-bit integer, in turn, without cache misses. The data set is, unfortunately, absolutely inflexible -- it's already as small as possible.

**Access pattern:** Each uint64_t is in fact an array of 4x4x4 bits, each bit representing the presence or absence of a voxel. This means sometimes I will be using half of one chunk and half of another, or even corners of 8 different 64-bit chunks.... I guess what this means is there is a high likelihood of a lack of alignment.

**How can I do this as fast as possible i.e. without thrashing the cache?**

P.S. The idea is that this code will ultimately run on a fairly wide range of architectures of at least a 64B cache line width, so I'd prefer this were absolutely as fast as possible. This also means I can't rely on MOVNTDQA, which anyway may incur a performance hit of it's own inspite of loading the 9th element directly to the CPU.

P.P.S. My knowledge of this area is fairly limited so please take it easy on me. But please spare me the premature optimisation comments; be sure that this is the 3% of this application that really counts.

Comment: Data-set usually describes the overall size - it seems you have 64B objects, but how many of them do you expect?

Comment: @Leeor I have 9x uint64_t = 68B total. I consider the extra one that I am comparing the other eight to, separate, for conceptual purposes. Hm, just thinking about memory layout...  see edit.

Comment: That depends on you target architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you get cache-misses?
Even if the comparing value is not in an register, i think your first uint64 array should be on one cache stage (or what ever it is called) and your other data in another. 
Your cache surely has some n-way associativity, that prevents your data row from being removed from the cache just by accessing your compare value.

Do not lose your time on Micro Optimizations. Improve your algorithms and data structures.

Comment: He didn't say the eight uint64 are in an array. If n is smaller than 8 and those 8 integer happens to locate at addresses that are exactly `SizeOfCacheLine*2^M` bytes from each other, there indeed could a cache conflict. This won't happen if they are completely randomly scattered in memory, or closely together like an array, but could happen in situations like across rows of an image whose row size is `SizeOfCacheLine*2^M`.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about it. If your dataset is really only 9 integers, most of it will likely be stored in registers anyway. Also, there isn't really any way to optimize cache usage without specifying an architecture, since cache structure *is* architecture dependent. If you can list several target architectures you may be able to find some commonalities that you can optimize toward, but without knowing those architectures, I don't think there's much we can do for you.

Lastly, this seems like a good example of optimizing too early. I would suggest you take the following steps:

1. Decide what your maximum acceptable run time is
2. Finish your program in C
3. Compile for all of your target architectures
4. For those platforms that don't meet your speed spec, hand-optimize the intermediate assembly files and recompile until you meet your spec.

Comment: You make some valid points. However I would like to remind you of the full quote: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." **This IS the 3% that counts.** AI, physics, rendering all rely on this being FAST.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer My apologies for assuming you hadn't already done the profiling to identify this code segment. I've seen too many optimization questions on SO where the OP hadn't done any work to identify the correct 3%, so I was replying a bit habitually. That was my mistake.

Comment: Not to seem unappreciative; Thanks for your help, I upvoted for the useful parts of your answer.